# How to change the trace width in an accordian object in alitum 22 without deleting the trace first?

Tags: pcb, altium, high-speed, trace

I have several accordion objects in altium. I need to change the trace width. If the trace is selected it won't show up the properties window to change the width. The only way I have found to change the width is delete the accordion, change the width and redraw it. Which can be cumbersome for a memory interface with 40+ lines.

Is there a good way to change the width of the trace in an accordian without deleting it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a PCB document with intact accordion objects handy to test it, but Robert Feranec's excellent blog contains [this entry](https://designhelp.fedevel.com/forum/main-forum/altium/17818-change-width-of-track-within-accordion):

> There are more methods:
>
> 1. Select them (tracks and accordians) and Route->Retrace Selected. Don't forget to set the new rule before. Track paths could be changed
>    depends on new rules!
> 2. All of PCB objects can always be editable in low levels by PCB List Panel. Change traces as you did it. Select Accordian nets on PCB
>    Panel->Unions->Interactive Length tunings. Rewrite Width column values
>    of track under PCB List Panel. Don't forget switch to edit mode. You
>    can edit more objects together. If you need have modify only widths,
>    this is the best.
> 3. You can convert accordians into free primitive via Tools->Explode Length Tuning To Free Primitive command. After this they are editable
>    as simple Tracks, Arcs.
>
> Attila

Comment: 1. Retrace only affects the tracks it doesn't affect the accordian